# House moved a bit more than I'm comfortable with

Tags: walls, structural

Until a couple years ago, we had an operating quarry nearby, with regular blasts. Smaller movements between the drywall plates were normal at the time and didn't worry me. (I got this confirmed by several contractors familiar with the area and how houses here react to the quarry blasts.) Since the quarry shut down a couple years ago, not even those smaller movements happened anymore.

But a few weeks ago, something bigger happened. Below is an image of two drywall plates that moved against each other. This is not only in one place, and one closet door frame is now a bit off so that the door needs some force to open/close because its top rubs against the frame.

I'm thinking of asking a structural engineer about this. What would they do to find out whether this is a problem?

[image: Drywall plates moving]

Comment: The usual common problem with drywall movement is fine cracks.  That almost looks like thin rubber coating that is squeeze together.  Drywall damage is usually not much of a concern, but checking the foundation would help to tell if more checking is needed.  I bet your foundation is a finish living space.

Comment: earth will move years after, watch your foundation for cracks

Comment: @crip659 perhaps "rubber coating"=latex paint at the drywall corner joint?

Comment: "Should I worry?" is asking for an opinion. "What's the price?" is explicitly off-topic. "Who should I call?" call back the people you've talked to before - you've already got a working relationship with them...

Comment: "'Should I worry?' is asking for an opinion." FWIW, there seem to be many questions here that ask for similar things (like "Is it a concern?").

"'Who should I call?' call back the people you've talked to before". I'm not sure they are qualified to answer this question. They seemed to be qualified to answer my questions at the time I asked them, but as I stated in my post, this looks different to me.

Comment: I certainly couldn't answer your question as now asked, but I'm sure someone can. VtR

Comment: "but I'm sure someone can" -- I hope so, and I hope that the edits are enough to reopen the post.

Comment: Hi Gerhard, you are still asking us to guess what another person would do. I tried to rephrase it. But it really isnt possible. Its possible the house has settled, which happens to many houses, even without a quarry. Is the floor level? Try rolling a marble on it. You really need to call an Engineer and listen to what they say.

Comment: Thanks, @RohitGupta, for helping me understand. AIUI, I'm not asking for a guess; to me, this is more like "what would a competent contractor do when putting in a new shower wall". This seems a question of a type that's asked here (and answered) all the time. "Call an engineer" sounds to me like "call a contractor", and so far I've had really bad experiences with half of them. (And it seems I'm not the only one.) So I'm trying to get some information about this before I call one.